# How to export createAsyncThunk chunks from one file to another?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I don't know why it gives me error as

> "ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'getVotes' before
> initialization"

here is my file with Thunks:

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import instance from "../../server";
import IVote from "../../models/vote";
import { add_user } from "./voteSlice";

export const getVotes = createAsyncThunk(
    "vote/getvote",
    async() => {
        const res = await instance.get<IVote>("vote/getvote");
        if (res.status === 200)
            return res.data; 
    }
)

export const addUser = createAsyncThunk(
    "vote/adduser",
    async(_, thunkApi) => {
        const res = await instance.get("vote/adduser");
        if(res.status === 204)
            thunkApi.dispatch(add_user());
    }
```

)

it works just fine if I export one chunk as :

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import instance from "../../server";
import IVote from "../../models/vote";
import { add_user } from "./voteSlice";

export const getVotes = createAsyncThunk(
    "vote/getvote",
    async() => {
        const res = await instance.get<IVote>("vote/getvote");
        if (res.status === 200)
            return res.data; 
    }
)
```

Then in my slice I have this

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import IVote from "../../models/vote";
import * as Thunk from "./voteThunks";

const initialState: IVote = {
//..//
};

const voteSlice = createSlice({
    name: "Vote",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        add_user: (state) => {
            state.users.push();
        }
    },
    extraReducers: {
        [Thunk.getVotes.fulfilled.type]: 
            (_, action: PayloadAction<IVote>) => {
            return action.payload
        }
    }
})
export const { add_user } = voteSlice.actions;
export default voteSlice.reducer;
```

, but if I export 2 it gives error.  How do I export it correctly ? Or should it be only one Thunk per file ?